# Как найти записи, у которых существует запись с датой не больше одного дня от предыдущей?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица:

- Idclient - Клиент
- Order - Заказ
- Date_time - Дата заказа
- Denial - Отказ

Нужно по клиенту найти заказы с отказом, дата которых отстаёт от предыдущего максимум на 1 день.

Например: `Date_time` = сегодня, нужно найти за сегодня и за вчера. Если такие заказы с отказами имеются, то нужно показать одобренные заказы по этому клиенту.

В этой задаче мне трудно понять логику поиска 2х заказов с шагом в день, да и заказов по клиенту может быть более 5-и, и даты этих заказов должны сравниваться друг с другом.

Как это можно реализовать ?

Comment: Добавте в вопрос тестовые данные и как выглядит ожидаемый результат (см. [как создать минимальный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На следующих данных (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1ce17c93f2e966cde3d391a5f719cc25)):

```
select * from clientOrder
/
  IDCLIENT    IDORDER ORDERDATE           DENIAL
---------- ---------- ------------------- ------
         1         11 2021-05-01 12:00:00 n     
         1         12 2021-05-02 12:00:00 y     
         1         13 2021-05-03 12:00:00 n     
         2         21 2021-05-01 12:00:00 n     
         2         22 2021-05-02 14:24:00 y     
         2         23 2021-05-03 12:00:00 n     
         3         31 2021-05-01 12:00:00 n     
         3         32 2021-05-01 12:00:00 n     
         3         33 2021-05-01 12:00:00 n     
         4         11 2021-05-01 12:00:00 y     
         4         11 2021-05-02 12:00:00 n     
         4         11 2021-05-03 12:00:00 n     
         9         99 2021-05-01 12:00:00 n
```

Ожидаю получить, согласно описанию в вопросе, заказы 11, 13 для клиента 1:

```
select * 
from clientOrder t1
where exists (
    select null from (
        select t2.*, lag (orderDate, 1, date'-4712-01-01') over (
            partition by Idclient order by orderDate asc) prevOrderDate
        from clientOrder t2
        where t2.Idclient = t1.Idclient)  
    where Denial = 'y' 
    and   orderDate-prevOrderDate <= 1)
and Denial = 'n'
```

Результат:

```
  IDCLIENT    IDORDER ORDERDATE           DENIAL
---------- ---------- ------------------- ------
         1         11 2021-05-01 12:00:00 n     
         1         13 2021-05-03 12:00:00 n
```

Comment: В конструкцию **lag**


`select t2.*, lag (orderDate, 1, date'-4712-01-01') over (
            order by orderDate asc) prevOrderDate`
можно добавить условие ?
Есть поле **отказ** и поле **причина отказа**.
Eсли я ограничиваю **причину отказа** в поле `where` то смещённая дата в `lag` не ограничивается, а только `orderDate`

Comment: @Akalit Насколько я понял, должно работать. В ответе есть ссылка на фиддле, поправте там данные и запрос и дайте комментарием обновлённую ссылку.

Comment: Не совсем, у меня в PL/SQL запрос не отрабатывает, не понимает это соединение `where t2.Idclient = t1.Idclient` но для меня важно было узнать про `lag / lead` для решения этого вопроса.

И для корректного сравнения времени по 1 клиенту мне понадобилось дописать `partition by`
А вопрос который я задал, удалось решить с помощью `with` в которой прописал нужные условия, а после по ней уже сравнивал даты. Благодарю вас за помощь !

Comment: @Akalit Рад был помочь! По поводу - partition by, да забыл, спасибо, поправил. Пожалуйста, всегда добавляйте в вопрос или коментарий ссылку на фиддле. Без неё трудно понять ход ваших мыслей, например, последние комментарии я понял только  частично, и то не уверен, что правильно.